# postgres error syntax error at or near "int" when creating a function

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to postgres. I got this error when try to run the following script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xyz(text) RETURNS INTEGER AS
'DECLARE result int;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) into result from tbldealercommissions
    WHERE 
    txtdealercode = $1;

    if result < 1 then returns 1; 
    else returns 2 ;
    end if;
END;
    '
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

The error is

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "int"
LINE 3: 'DECLARE result int;
```

not sure what cause this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is unsuitable:

> ```
> LANGUAGE sql
> ```

use this instead:

> ```
> LANGUAGE plpgsql
> ```

The syntax you are trying to use is not pure SQL language but the procedural PL/pgSQL language. In PostgreSQL you can install different languages and PL/pgSQL is only primus inter pares in that regard. This also means that you might get the error message, that this language is not installed. In that case use

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which actives it. Depending on the version of PostgreSQL you might need superuser rights to do this step.

Have fun.

Comment: Hi A.H, I changed language to plpgsql and got this error:ERROR:  language "plpgsql" does not exist
            HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.

Comment: Added some explanation in the post.

Comment: @Shiver: Since PostgreSQL **9.0**, [language PL/pgSQL is installed by default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/release-9-0.html). Additionally, you can: `CREATE OR REPLACE LANGUAGE plpgsql;` to be sure.

Comment: Great thanks A.H I run create command and managed to create the function. Thanks guys for all the help.

Comment: Please "vote" and "accept" the usefull answers [as described in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

Not only are you using the wrong language (as noted by A.H.) but there is `returns` keyword, you want `return`. You might want to use a different delimiter to avoid running into problems with string literals in your functions, `$$` is pretty common. I think your function should look more like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xyz(text) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE result int;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into result
    from tbldealercommissions
    where txtdealercode = $1;

    if result < 1 then return 1; 
    else return 2;
    end if;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```